# Django web app with Windows Docker container on Azure: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '10.40.0.7:30015'. You may need to add '10.40.0.7' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django, windows, azure, docker

I deployed my Django app with Windows Docker container to Azure app services. The app works fine locally. But after deploying to the server, the kudu site log gives:

```
Bad Request: /
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 69702
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '10.40.0.7:30015'. You may need to add '10.40.0.7' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

I know that I can add allowed IP addresses to settings.py and my .env file. But the problem is that Azure uses dynamic IP addresses. So with each push to the container and restart the app, my public IP address changes.
How can I fix this?

Comment: you need a static ip

Answer (score 1):

It is advised to use a fully qualified domain name, but if you are just testing or security is not critical, you can just use `*` for [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)